# Problema com do while

Tags: java, do-while

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    BancoConta p1 = new BancoConta();
    p1.inicio();

}

public void inicio() {
    do {
        System.out.println("Para criar conta bancária: (1)");
        System.out.println("Para visualizar conta: (2)");
        escolha = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(escolha);
    } while (escolha!=1||escolha!=2);
    System.out.println("saiu");
}
```

Não está printando o **"saiu"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro que a variável `escolha` não aparece declarada neste código.

Mas o grande problema é que você usou `||` ao invés de `&&`. Olhe isso:

```
escolha!=1||escolha!=2
```

Pense bem, se `escolha` for 1, temos que ela é diferente de 2, então continua no `do-while`. Se ela for 2, então é diferente de 1 e também continua.

O que você queria era isso:

```
escolha != 1 && escolha != 2
```